# Let X,Y be two random variables. Give two equivalent definitions for them being independent.

Tags: probability

Let X,Y be two random variables. Give two equivalent definitions for them being independent, using d.f's or density functions. Show that the two definitions are equivalent.

Is the question asking me to show that 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) \iff F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_{X}(x)F_{Y}(y)\quad???$$

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is the leftside understood to be probability mass functions if the r.v.s are discrete and density functions if they are continuous? If so then yes, but you have to divide into cases

Answer (score 0):

It wants you to define the notion of the r.v.s $X$ and $Y$ being independent in two ways as follows:

1.) Define it in terms of the cumulative distributions ( I will give you this one)

$\\$

Definition 1: They are independent iff $F(x,y) = F_1(x)F_2(y)$ for every pair $(x,y)$

$\\$

2.) Define it in terms of marginal densities $($the little $f's)$:

$ \\ $

Definition 2: They are independent if ____________

$\\$

Next it wants you to show that $X$ and $Y$ will be independent under definition 1 if and only if they are independent under definition 2. This is the equivalence part.

Note: Definition 2 might have to be divided into 2 parts depending on whether you are doing only discrete, only continuous, or both types of distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the measure theoretic part of the equivalence. I am assuing, of course, that the $(X,Y)$ has a density $f_{X,Y}$ so that $f_X$ and $f_Y$ also exist. If $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X (x)f_Y (y)$ then it is immediate that $F_{X,Y} (x,y)=F_X (x) F_Y (y)$: just write the probabilities in terms of the densities and apply Fubini's Theorem. For the converse part write $h(x,y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)-f_X (x)f_Y (y)$ and note that the integral of h over $(-\infty, x] \times (-\infty,y]$ is 0. Write this equation for two values of x and subtract one equation from the other. Then do a similar thing in y. Integral of h over $(a,b] \times (c,d]$ becomes 0 for all choices of a

Comment: (Continuation) of a<b and c<d ; these rectangles generate the Borel sigma algebra and hence h=0 almost everywhere.